# is this venn diagram of posets, osets and lattices correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm trying to organize the concepts of ordered sets to understand what types of ordered sets are subsets of each other or intersect in some way, for that purpose I'm building a Venn diagram with those concepts.

Is this diagram correct? if it's not could you point out how it should be changed to be correct? also please point me out any important structures in set theory and order theory that might be as important as the ones in the diagram but are not present (probably because I don't know their existence)

[image]

Comment: spelling: totally ordered sets.

Comment: A well-ordered set could be a bounded lattice too. Or a finite lattice for that matter.

Comment: A linearly ordered set that is finite, is well-ordered and a finite lattice etc. So there is more overlap.

Comment: A one-element poset is in the intersection of all these classes, including antichains. An empty poset is in many of them as well (but some version of definitions disallow empty algebras or posets).